# How do I add index to dynamically added elements in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a PDF viewer in HTML with a thumbnail view on the side. I read each page and dynamically append a canvas to the thumbnail window for that page. I have already added the onclick event to change the active state of particular thumbnail clicked. How do I add the 'function renderFullPage(pagenumber){ ..... }' to the event. Specifically how do I return the pagenumber associated with the particular thumbnail?

```
function renderFullPDF() {
            var wrapper = document.getElementById('pdfPreview');
            function renderPages(pdfDoc) {
                for (var num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++) {
                    pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function renderPage(page, num) {
                        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        canvas.className = "pdfPageThumb";
                        var viewport = page.getViewport(canvas.width / page.getViewport(1.0).width);
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        var renderContext = {
                            canvasContext: ctx,
                            viewport: viewport
                        };
                        canvas.height = viewport.height;
                        canvas.width = viewport.width;
                        wrapper.appendChild(canvas)
                        page.render(renderContext);

                        canvas.addEventListener("click", function () {
                            var current = document.getElementById('pdfPreview').getElementsByClassName("active");
                            if (current.length > 0) {
                                current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
                            }
                            this.className += " active";
                        });
                    });
                }
            }

            pdfjsLib.disableWorker = true;
            pdfjsLib.getDocument('myfile.pdf').then(renderPages);

        }
```

Comment: `canvas.setAttribute('data-index', num)`, and later `canvas.getAttribute('data-index')` to get and use it

Comment: @Taplar I get `undefined` in getAttribute.

Comment: Where did you add the setAttribute?

Comment: Right after ```canvas.className = "pdfPageThumb";``` Like this: ```canvas.className = "pdfPageThumb";  canvas.setAttribute('data-index', num);```

Comment: Yeah, that seems valid.  Should be working

Comment: ah! num is undefined. apparently it's not passed down the .then function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must properly scope your variables and parameters. The promise returned by getPage(num) likely only passes a single parameter to **then** which means that you have created a variable named num in a new scope that is initialized to **undefined**.  I would suggest you add an anonymous function call with **num** as the parameter, as follows. This way num will be defined to the correct value when the promise is filled.

```
function renderFullPDF() {
            var wrapper = document.getElementById('pdfPreview');
            function renderPages(pdfDoc) {
                for (var num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++) {
                    (function (num) { // Anonymous function creates new scope when called
                    pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function renderPage(page) {
                        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        canvas.className = "pdfPageThumb";
                        // from @Taplar but likely optional at this
                        // point since num from this anonymous
                        // function scope will be available
                        // (captured) in your event listener.
                        canvas.setAttribute('data-index', num); 
                        var viewport = page.getViewport(canvas.width / page.getViewport(1.0).width);
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        var renderContext = {
                            canvasContext: ctx,
                            viewport: viewport
                        };
                        canvas.height = viewport.height;
                        canvas.width = viewport.width;
                        wrapper.appendChild(canvas)
                        page.render(renderContext);

                        canvas.addEventListener("click", function () {
                            var current = document.getElementById('pdfPreview').getElementsByClassName("active");
                            if (current.length > 0) {
                                current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
                            }
                            this.className += " active";
                        });
                    });

                   })(num); // Pass num parameter
                }
            }

            pdfjsLib.disableWorker = true;
            pdfjsLib.getDocument('myfile.pdf').then(renderPages);

        }
```

Comment: Thank you Ralph. That's precisely what I did once I realized that num was undefined.